# Unable to start Pantheon

Tags: pantheon, gnome

My system, which runs oneElementary OS, was acting up (package manager wouldn't open, system wouldn't restart, etc.) so I did a hard reset on it. Now when I boot it up and try to log in I get the error `unable to launch "gnome-session --session=pantheon" X session --- "gnome-session --session=pantheon" not found; falling pack to default session.`

It then brings me back to the log in screen. I can still boot into terminal, but I can't get X to open at all.. Any ideas? I really need back in

Comment: What means "hard reset"? Do you have internet connection?

Comment: By hard reset i mean holding down the power button until the computer turns off and then turning it back on. And yes. I ended up reinstalling my OS though

Answer (score 2):

Check if you have broken soft links in `/usr/bin`:

```
cd /usr/bin
for x in * .[!.]* ..?*; do if [ -L "$x" ] && ! [ -e "$x" ]; then echo "$x"; fi; done
```

This will list all broken soft links. If you have any, specially the `which` command, there's your answer. Just remove the broken link and relink again:

```
cd /usr/bin
sudo rm which
sudo ln -s /bin/which which
```

> In my case, I had installed some Node.js packages globally (entries added to `/usr/bin`), and one of them was replacing the default `which` command with a Node.js custom one.
>
> Then, at some point I switched the Node.js `--global` installations from `/usr/local/...` to my `$HOME` (to [solve a problem](https://github.com/sindresorhus/guides/blob/master/npm-global-without-sudo.md) with `node-gyp`), after which I ended up with **plenty of broken links on `/usr/bin`**.

If you want you can remove all broken links (at your own risk) using:

```
sudo su -
cd /usr/bin
for x in * .[!.]* ..?*; do if [ -L "$x" ] && ! [ -e "$x" ]; then rm "$x"; fi; done
```

Comment: Excellent first post, thank you for your contribution!

Answer (score 1):

First get to a TTY terminal/command prompt with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>. (If it won't open, boot the computer into safe mode.)

Then edit this file: **`gksudo gedit /usr/share/xsessions/pantheon.desktop`**

and remove the line **`Exec=gnome-session --session=pantheon`** to kill your old session.

(There is a `gnome.desktop` file too with a similar line to remove, if for some reason you're using GNOME instead of Pantheon.)

Some potentially helpful links: [1](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2166672), [2](https://askubuntu.com/a/629329/49899),